# Redirect Laravel в Middleware

Tags: laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста есть Middleware с проверкой зарегестрирован ли пользователь в папке /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware, там есть 2 метода

```
 protected function unauthenticated($request, array $guards)
    {
        throw new AuthenticationException(
            'Unauthenticated.', $guards, $this->redirectTo($request)
        );
    }
 protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        return redirect('');
    }
```

Я хочу в методе redirectTo перенаправить на страницу, но `return redirect('');` не работает

Подскажите как можно это реализовать ?

Answer (score 0):

Middleware, который вы хотите использовать лежит в `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate`